# Change brackets to parentheses in filename

Tags: windows-10, powershell-5.0

I need to recursively change the square brackets in the names of audio files to parentheses within multiple folders.

Original name:
`Gonna Get Along Without You Now [Strelka Sounds Edit].mp3`

I tried:

```
ls $location* -Recurse -Include *.mp3 | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -Replace '[\[\]]', '('}
```

The result was:
`Gonna Get Along Without You Now (Strelka Sounds Edit(.mp3`

Desired result:
`Gonna Get Along Without You Now (Strelka Sounds Edit).mp3`

How to make the parentheses in the correct order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do two sequential `-replace`s, one for the [ -> ( and one for the ] -> ), e.g., `$foo -replace '\[','(' -replace '\]',')'` - or, if you want to avoid having to escape the regex-significant characters, use the `.replace()` method of the string object, `$foo.replace('[','(').replace(']',')')`

Comment: It worked. thanks.